# PHPStorm: PHP Syntax Highlighting editing / adding rules, and Customization

Tags: php, syntax, highlighting, phpstorm, rules

Hey I was looking around online and couldn't find anything about how to modify the syntax highlighting rules. I am trying to add a rule for PHP variables inside of double quoted strings. In Aptana they have a rule where these variables are highlighted which I find extremely useful as I do a lot with PHP vars inside double quoted strings. This is similar to the <<

I would also like to be able to specify sets of rules, for instance on heredocs:

```
    <<<HTML
        <html>
           <div>$phpvar</div>
        </html>
    HTML
```

I want The html highlighted as HTML for specifically <<

Anyone know how to customized / edit the rules for the syntax highlighting?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php.

Comment: Any questions about a specific IDE probably won't get an answer here. However, I use PHPStorm myself and I happen to know that they have some of the best support forums available. Check out their community forums here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/ I'm sure if you post your question there someone will have an answer almost immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into settings

> File > Default Settings

There you can select how your code is formatted wrapped etc.

For colors go to:

> Preferences > Editor (under IDE settings) > Colors & Fonts

There you can play around with colors, highlighting, background, fonts etc